# Why is a line break being added to my generated SQL and breaking my script?

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr, dbplyr

I created an R environment on Conda 23.1 and below is my sessionInfo:

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)

Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo)

Matrix products: default

BLAS/LAPACK: /data/conda/envs/$USER/r_mamba_dev/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.21.so

 

locale:

[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C             

 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8   

 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8  

 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                

 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C           

[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

 

attached base packages:

[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base    

 

other attached packages:

[1] abfunctions_1.0 arrow_9.0.0     sparklyr_1.8.2  glue_1.6.2    

 [5] dbplyr_2.3.3    lubridate_1.9.2 forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.0 

 [9] dplyr_1.1.2     purrr_1.0.1     readr_2.1.4     tidyr_1.3.0   

[13] tibble_3.2.0    ggplot2_3.4.2   tidyverse_2.0.0 repr_1.1.4    

 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

[1] pbdZMQ_0.3-8     tidyselect_1.2.0 colorspace_2.0-3 vctrs_0.6.0    

 [5] generics_0.1.3   htmltools_0.5.3  yaml_2.3.6       base64enc_0.1-3

 [9] utf8_1.2.2       rlang_1.1.0      pillar_1.9.0     withr_2.5.0    

[13] DBI_1.1.3        bit64_4.0.5      uuid_1.1-0       lifecycle_1.0.3

[17] munsell_0.5.0    gtable_0.3.1     evaluate_0.18    tzdb_0.3.0     

[21] fastmap_1.1.0    parallel_4.2.2   fansi_1.0.3      IRdisplay_1.1  

[25] openssl_2.0.6    scales_1.2.1     IRkernel_1.3.1   jsonlite_1.8.4 

[29] config_0.3.1     bit_4.0.5        askpass_1.1      hms_1.1.2      

[33] digest_0.6.30    stringi_1.7.8    grid_4.2.2       cli_3.6.1      

[37] tools_4.2.2      magrittr_2.0.3   crayon_1.5.2     pkgconfig_2.0.3

[41] ellipsis_0.3.2   timechange_0.2.0 assertthat_0.2.1 httr_1.4.4     

[45] rstudioapi_0.14  R6_2.5.1         compiler_4.2.2
```

As an example problem here is a simple query.  I'm querying a hadoop table called `events` through spark with the following code:

```
tokens<- events %>%
    compute("tokens")
```

I would expect this to create a table in spark called "tokens".  However when I run it i get the following error:

```
Error in `db_save_query.DBIConnection()`:
! Can't save query to "tokens".
Caused by error:
! org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
no viable alternative at input 'CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW \n"tokens"'(line 2, pos 0)

== SQL ==
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW
"tokens" AS SELECT *
^^^
FROM `db`.`events `
```

As an added note this error only seems to occur when I use the `compute` or `pivot_wider` functions.  If I were to run a simple example like this i would not get the error:

```
tokens<- events
```

I have tried updating sparklyr, tidyverse, dplyr, dbplyr, and no updates have resolved it.  I've also tried creating entirely new code blocks thinking I put the '\n' in there somehow but that didn't fix it.  I also tried putting the entire code on one line and that didn't fix it either.

For some reason it *appears* as though a new line is being entered and that's causing an issue in the SQL that's being translated.  I'm not sure how to solve that problem so I can run the R script as normal.

Comment: `compute` results in a remote temporary table ([documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/compute.html)). You have the right database permissions to create temporary tables/views?